# Block Zoom of a Web-based Project in a Touchable Screen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am developing a `Web-based project` that runs on a `Localhost` that needs to block the `zoom` of the user interface on it. Is there any way to block this using `JavaScript`? In addition, can I block this using only `Google Chrome`?

I know it is not a good practice to do so, but in this case is not that important. Mostly, due to the fact that the only Human-Interaction Tool in this desktop App is a touchable screen and there is a requirement to block the Zoom of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the code

```
<script>
(function(){
setInterval("document.body.style.zoom=1/window.devicePixelRatio",0);
var newview=document.createElement("meta");
newview.id="viewport";
newview.name="viewport";
newview.content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1";
document.body.parentElement.children[0].appendChild(newview);
})()
</script>
```

Add a comment if you have any questions or problems with this.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to make it work using this code and I will let you know @SBoys3.com